# Good practice for layered application with internationalization

Tags: java, internationalization

I'm designing a new application in JSE which I want to internationalize.
I've never done such an application. I'm looking for the best practices about the internationalization. The application while be writing the translated data in files or DB. I've searched about best practices but I didn't found anything about my main question(the first one).

- Should I put all the internationalization data in some layer or next to the object they are about ?
- Could I directly use the properties files as a kind of enum to do a switch case ?
  Or can I reverse engineer the data catched and know the default internationalize value and work with it?

Comment: This might help a little bit:
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-locales-and-resource-bundles-to-internationalize-my-application.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did encounter several strategies. I would start with a properties file.

One factor is that the data must be professionally *maintained*:

- keep it in version control.
- keep a version number for us humans, "1.0.23"
- keep the texts ordered and nice, to help translation.
- keep a second properties file with a glossary for consistent translation.

Undermore I did see generating properties or java ListResourceBundles from DocBook XML, Excel, translation memories. And yes, database.

Maintenance of data must be done careful, as several different parties will use the text at different times.
Programming tools, consistency checks and preparing data, communicating are tasks not to neglect.

Properties files are not entirely ideal, but IDEs have generally some support for them.

Set up everything for UTF-8, though take notice that properties files use ISO-8859-1, but you can use \uXXXX escaping or do a encoding conversion in your build process. ListResourceBundle java sources, generated than, would be an alternative.

Comment: Thanks, this help a lot, but could I put all the properties files in a dedicated package or should the properties files standing next to the files who use them ? And is reverse ingineering a possible way to work on a switch case when reading back the created files ?

Comment: One wants to prevent repeating texts, or different styles. That would mean having at least one big file as basis for translation in a top package like i18n or such. Whether you want a properties file per module, and some integration to the main translation memory is a matter of choice. On the last question: one could generate a test locale with entries like "xyz=[xyz]" and/or on a missing translation log it, show "[xyz]"?

Comment: So I should make a big file containing all generic translation ( add/delete/...) and put the specific translation in little files ?  
What I want to do is read the translated text in the files/DB and seek in the properties files to find the value's "name" switch to the default properties file and use this new value on a switch case. Is this realisable ? Wouldn't this took too much time ?

Comment: You could use one single ResourceBundle, and when it grows too large improve the performance by turning it in a ListResourceBundle, a .java with a string array/"mapping."  On the other hand I found XML as source for genation of properties elegant too: comments and hierarchical grouping were possible. Simple DocBook XML I used in one case.